# Hide transparent content under other transparent content?

Tags: html, css, sass, background, styling

Is there any way to make a transparent header and multiple div containers and don't show them under the transparent header?
(If the header is 50px -> content 'stops' showing if it gets to top 50px)

Giving the header the same background-image as the rest and changeing z-index isn't a possibility.

The header shouldn't get darker when i scroll the content into it.
 [watch here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VgEaLq)

```
    <body>

  <header>
    header
  </header>
  <main>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


    <div class="content">

    </div>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


  </main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

css

```
 html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100vh; }

header {
  height: 10%;
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-bottom: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #636363;
  z-index: 10; }
  header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Verdana;
    margin-left: 5%;
    top: 50%; }

.content {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 5; }

footer {
  height: 10vh;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-bottom: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 5px -5px #636363;
  z-index: 10; }
```

Comment: Welcome to the community.  Could you please supply some code so we can see what you are working with?

Comment: Yeah, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding another div in between via z-index CSS?

Or you could find the steady colour you want (with 'ColorPick Eyedropper' chrome extension if you don't have another tool) and not making the header translucent at all

Are you looking for the Roblox graphic effect where partially transparent objects are not visible behind other translucent objects?

Comment: I wanted to do this with a picture, so it isn't a option to don't make it transparent.

Comment: I think such a Roblox graphical effect should work. you got any ideas to make it possible in my code?

Comment: @TheRealEricCartman images can have opacity and it is animatable

Comment: @TheRealEricCartman You would likely need JQuery and that is not my area

Comment: @TheRealEricCartman If you just want a solid color, I think I may have fixed your problem:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VgEaLq